# Default priority inheritance policy of pthread mutexes on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, pthreads

I have looked around on SO, but did not find an answer to this: When creating pthread mutexes in a Linux userspace program, which policy do these mutexes have by default? See https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol

It seems the best default policy would be priority ceiling, i.e.  PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT, at least for my application ;)

Also, can I set priority inheritance policy on C++ std::mutexes as well, I suspect a C++ std::mutex will be a futex in Linux anyway, as are pthread mutexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.html#tag_16_443):

> The default value of the attribute shall be PTHREAD_PRIO_NONE.

Unfortunately, there is no way of setting this on a `std::mutex` as far as I know. There is a `std::mutex::native_handle` function that can be used to get access to the underlying `pthread_mutex_t *`. However, it is already too late to change any attributes on it, since `pthread_mutex_init` is executed by the `std::mutex` constructor, and according to the [POSIX standard again](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html):

> Attempting to initialize an already initialized mutex results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and short answer, accepted. I guess I will have to use C++ std threads with naked posix mutexes then, since I do not want PTHREAD_PRIO_NONE. I can probably achieve RAII unlock of the mutex anyway with some RAII wrapper. Btw, would be nice if the Linux manpage contained info about the default policy.